# Implementing a specific like counter

Tags: php, html, ajax

Alright, this is quite a strange and not very specific question, but stackoverflow is my last hope, so here it goes:

I've been building my own website based on a CMS for the last weeks, and so far, I managed to fix every problem I've encountered with patience, luck and/or a good search, even though I have just some basic HTML/CSS knowledge. But now I'm completely stuck at implementing a like counter. The coder of the CMS created a small snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/3129327) with some basic instructions. I followed them, yet I'm unable to get it working. I can recieve the error

`{"status":"error","msg":"The post could not be found"}`

, yet I can't increase the counter (it just redirects me to my Error-Page) and I have no clue what to do exactly with the Ajax-Example. I've already tried to ask in their forum, but nobody answered me. I tried to learn from the code of a working [website](http://csspandemic.com/), but that didn't help either. I'm completely stuck, and haven't been able to get it working using Google.

So, it would be great if somebody could explain to me how to implement it, or point me to a similar example.

I know that this is a strange question and I fully understand if you can't/won't help me, but thanks in advance anyways.

Comment: link you web, so that we can actually see the issue

Comment: did you see what they say [here](https://gist.github.com/3129327#usage)? They report exactly the error you are having.

Comment: @DanieleB Yes, I've seen this. This was just a test to see if I can at least get this specific error, so the snippet seems to be correctly installed. I just don't know how to implement it correctly...

Comment: tried the firebug to montior the request and responces? what do you see there?

Comment: if your website is online you could provide the url

Comment: @NewBee There isn't much too link, since I'm not shure how to implement it. Based on the example website, I link a button the following way: `<a href="blog/like/post:<?php echo html($article->uid()) ?>">`, the same way they described it. That's it.

Comment: It appears that you have to include the full post name into the $.getJSON URI. So example.com/blog/like:title-of-post. That error occurs when that bit of the URL isn't there. Does the UID display the same kind of thing as the example?

Comment: <a href="http://youcompletewebURI.com/blog/like/post:<?php echo html($article->uid()) ?>"> tried this?

Comment: @NewBee Doesn't work, but thank you.

Comment: @Daniele B The site is developed locally. I've added the AJAX-Example on the bottom of the page, now I just get 404-Errors, like `GET http://localhost/kirby/screenshots/like/post:test 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:3
send jquery.min.js:3
st.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:3
st.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:3
st.extend.getJSON jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function)`

Comment: @Syfaro I've added the URL of a working post into the script, yet I only recieve 404-Errors, as described above.

Comment: did you include all your javascript properly in the html file?

Comment: @DanieleB `<script type = "text/javascript" >
$.getJSON('http://localhost/kirby/screenshots/like/post:test', function(r) {

  if(r == undefined || r.status == 'error') {
    return alert('Likes could not be updated');
  } else {
    return alert('Likes have been updated. New Likes count: ' + r.likes);
  }

});
</script>` As I said, I've added an specific URL for testing. Placed it before calling the footer of the page.

Comment: sorry it is too difficult without seeing the code. Apparently there is some function overriding. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750541/jquery-submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is really weird, but today I fixed the problem by using ";" instead of ":". So the URL should be localhost/kirby/screenshots/like/post;test and everything works. This doesn't make any sense for me, since all existing themes use ":" , guess I changed something in my config. Just leaving this here if someone else has a similar problem.